# How to set properly STANFORD_MODELS VARIABLE?

Tags: python, bash

My bashrc lines

```
export STANFORD_MODELS="/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"
export STANFORD_MODELS="/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"
export STANFORD_MODELS="/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"
export STANFORD_MODELS="/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/example.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz"
```

When I go to Python shell

```
print (os.environ.get('STANFORD_MODELS'))
/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/example.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz
```

Why is only the last one printed out?

Should I change my .bashrc?

Comment: There is no way for a Bash variable to have more than one value. Each time you define a new value, you overwrite the previous value. (Also, doing `export` every time is superfluous; you only need to `export` a variable once, and then it's exported.)

Comment: I search on web it seems I should use :,right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html) you can set the variable to a colon-separated list of entries, just like the standard `PATH` variable.

```
export STANFORD_MODELS="/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz:/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz:/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz:/home/milenko/stanford-ner-2018-10-16/classifiers/example.serialized.ncc.ncc.ser.gz"
```